# Simple Diffuse Texture Bake Fails

Tags: modeling, shaders

I am trying to quite literally bake some bread. The issue that I am encountering is that my *diffuse* bake leaves me with a predominantly black and untextured  image. Note that there are also little extra artifacts of bread in the bake that I can see though.

The UV unwrapping seems to be correctly detected, since alpha pixels seem to be displaying in the bake, so I don't believe that that is the problem.

I am also quite sure that the problem isn't related to the *metalness* of the BSDF like other posts have described. Both my high quality model and the low quality model have metalness set to `0.000`.

What might I be doing wrong here?

[This is the tutorial that I am attempting to replicate btw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yx9TvvnxCAM)

**EDIT**: Here is the Blend File https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VvPWEQGB5qphXhHoWXhNapPzgWzR103a/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: hello please pack your image and share your file

Comment: @moonboots I have packed images and shared .blend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the high-poly at the same position as the low-poly: Select both the 2 objects and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> then bake again.